# Chain condition (ACC and DCC ) for a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group that satisfies both chain conditions (ACC & DCC ) and there exists a group $H$ with $G×G≅H×H$, we can say $G≅H$?
If G satisfies both chain conditions and K and H groups satisfies both chain conditions then G=K×H satisfies both chain conditions.

Comment: What are $G$ and $H$? Groups? $X$-groups? Rings? Modules?

Comment: G and H are groups

Comment: Your second question is also confusing. You say $G$ satisfies both and then asks if $G$ satisfies both.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is answered by the [Krull-Schmidt theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem).

(See Isaac's *Algebra*, chapter 10 for an exposition.)

Comment: no i think it is not right

Comment: @user149120 What isn't? The theorem is certainly true.

Comment: the theory is true but i do not it apply in this question.

Comment: @user149120  I think you can. For $G \times G$ is then of finite length, so we can write it as direct sum of its indecomposable parts. Then one knows that the indecomposable parts must be evenly divided into two copies of $G$ and two copies of $H$. This tells us that there are the same number of each of the indecomposable subgroups in $G$ and $H$, so that they are equal. (This can be made more formal with teh summand multiplicity function - page 139 in Isaacs.) In fact, your question is just corollary 10.18 in Isaacs.

Comment: very thanks, it is true